# mod_rewrite redirect folder to URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've been trying for the last few hours to do something that seems simple..

```
http://www.mydomain.com/u/username
```

redirect that to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/goto.php?u=username
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^u/(.*)$ goto.php?u=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Edit:** To redirect using a HTTP 302/301 response use this:

```
RewriteRule ^u/(.*)$ goto.php?u=$1 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^u/(.*)$ goto.php?u=$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: hi that works, but i think i asked for the wrong thing. i want it to do this but send to that link, not cloak it.

Comment: Is it on a different domain then?

Comment: If you want the actual URL to change as well then you will need to maybe use the .htaccess and then use header to change the URL on the browser `$username = $_GET["u"];
        header("Location: /goto.php?u=" .$username.");
        exit;`

Nothing should be sent to the browser before the header, for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

In apache or IIS?

in apache you could use an .htaccess with (in the u folder)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ goto.php?u=$2 [L]
```

If on IIS and you have the latest version, you can import .htaccess into it quite easily with a tool that comes with it